# .bashrc not read on WSL if $HOME contains spaces

Tags: bash, quoting, home, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently: [Specified a home directory path for a user in /etc/passwd with spaces in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542434/specify-a-home-directory-path-for-a-user-in-etc-passwd-with-spaces-in-it/542447#542447) but now my `.bashrc` doesn't source properly when I open a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS WSL window, so I have to `source` it manually...which works with `source ~/.bashrc`, but curiously does not work with `source $HOME/.bashrc`, but oddly does work with `source "$HOME"/.bashrc`.

So [Jeff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) on the previous question thought that maybe the issue is that something else is sourcing it without the quotes around it.

In fact a similar issue caused me to [fork git hub project](https://github.com/leeand00/kanban.bash/commit/d54b1ef8a1cf9b6aacced5728eb3ce1db1aaf6c8) in which a similar error was occurring; [I attributed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531852/ambigious-redirect-when-using-alias-to-export-environment-variable-of-path-with) it to be because I was using mingw64 / git-bash for Windows, but that wasn't the issue at all because now it's occurring in WSL...er at least I think that's the case...

Comment: don't you think the problem is simply word-splitting of the unquoted $HOME?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, but my question is what is running it when I open my terminal, so I can fix the issue there?  Because I can't re-export `$HOME` unless I'm using `.bashrc` to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I got hung up on your *test* of `source $HOME/.bashrc` which failed. Your actual question is centered around whatever's calling it that way.

Comment: @Gilles I have a couple of different windows up, and I get different outputs (I guess this is from different things I changed in `/etc/passwd` as at one point I tried to set the user's login shell to `tmux`; the one that has `tmux` running when I run `$-` gives me `smi`.  There are two other ones which don't appear to have tmux running and the one gives me `himBH` and the other one has `vim` running (without `tmux`) and that one reads `hBc` when I run `$-`

Comment: @Gilles The fresh one I opened also reads `himBH` when I run `$-`

Comment: My bad, `$-` doesn't show whether bash is a login shell. Check your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> curiously does not work with `source $HOME/.bashrc`

That's normal: [it isn't supposed to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766). `source "$HOME/.bashrc"` runs instructions from the file `.bashrc` in your home directory, but `source $HOME/.bashrc` takes the path to `.bashrc`, splits it at whitespace, and runs instructions from the file whose name is the part up to the first space and uses the other parts as positional arguments (available as `"$@"` from code in `.bashrc`). (That's assuming there are no wildcards in the value of `HOME`.)

Normally nothing would run a command like `source ~/.bashrc`: bash already does this when it starts. A likely explanation is that the WSL window runs a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). When bash is a login shell, [it doesn't load `.bashrc`, it loads `.bash_profile` or `.profile` instead](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980). Most people work around this quirk by [sourcing `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122187/is-there-a-bash-file-that-will-be-always-sourced-in-interactive-mode-no-matter-i/122188#122188). Check your `.bash_profile` (or if you don't have one your `.profile`, they might have the erroneous `source $HOME/.bashrc` or `. $HOME/.bashrc` instead of one of the correct methods (`source ~/.bashrc`, or if you like being verbose `source "$HOME/.bashrc"`, or either of these with `.` instead of `source`).